# Magento, what is the difference between getPrice and getFinalPrice

Tags: magento

Just exactly as the title explains, in Magento, what is the difference between these two:

```
$product->getPrice();
```

v

```
$product->getFinalPrice();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Get final price is with discount included.

Comment: Is there any tax involved with getFinal price or is this simply the product price entered into the admin area along with discount

Comment: Tax is not included in the final price. If you want to add sales tax you have to call `Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($product, $product->getFinalPrice());`

Comment: it looks like this method does not respect the SpecialToDate, at least on magento 1.9x

Answer (score 2):

getFinalPrice check if have some discount on product and if this discount is active, the method apply the discount and return the literal "Final Price", if you check for getPrice() you'll have just he simple price from this product.

Comment: I have just tested and getFinalPrice does not bring up the discounted price or special price either

Comment: If don't bring the discount is becouse discount isn't applicable.

Comment: Discount rule is set specfically against the product sku

Comment: And the interval of time, its ok?

Comment: Yes, set from yesterday with no end date

Comment: You can look on Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price and see by yourself. It's some condition aren't working right.

Comment: @MartyWallace - Define "test".

Comment: Did you run reindexing.